# Elliptical Background Gradient

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I would like to recreate the background gradient [shown here](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/2952/gradientt.png) on my web page. Unlike a simple linear gradient it doesn't work well repeated (as an image) such that it can fill a variable length. Can anyone recommend a method to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing the idea but there is something you can start with here: http://jsfiddle.net/yvsV7/

Comment: Almost... I tried that out in chrome and it renders as two dark bands from top to bottom. Changing the position from absolute to relative fixes the problem but then the gradient scrolls up and off the page as the content grows.

Comment: Also note that there are two subtle gradients down in each corner which should only be present when at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Re the first comment: weird, I used Chrome to put together the example. Which version are you using? And I didn't quite get the point about scrolling. Do you want the background to remain static regardless of scrolling or something?

Comment: I am running 18.0.1025.168. I placed that in the background and I have my content all wrapped in a div on top of it. I am not sure if that is what I want but I'd like to see it. The example you gave looks quite nice on my landing page but the other pages have much more content. The example you gave doesn't look so nice at that point because the effect is gone after you scroll down. I was thinking that I could keep the background static as you scroll.

Comment: That worked! I have marked this as answered but still have one little issue that would make this perfect. Specifying percentages for location of the gradient works well vertically (always in the center) but it does not work well horizontally as I have a div with my content which is a fixed width. Is there a way to locate that gradient with respect to the center of the screen rather than the top left? I'd like to make it center-400pixels for example.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work cross-browser, as the `window.onmove` handler is present only in IE :(

Comment: Bummer! Do you see any clean way to do this with an image? I was thinking maybe 3 absolute positioned divs(top, middle, bottom) with fixed height and 100% width. The middle would get a background image of the radial gradient and I should be able to position it with respect to the center using top and margin. Finally set the z-order so that it sits behind the content. Thoughts?

Comment: AFAUI, you want the background to remain static with respect to the desktop, regardless of the browser window movements, right? In order to do that, you would need to track the window motion in the first place. You cannot do that in Chrome (based on my search in the internets.)